# Vim errorformat multiline string

Tags: javascript, vim, syntastic, errorformat, flowtype

I'm trying to parse this error output for [`Flow`](http://flowtype.org). In the first error, it's the second file and line number that really matters, not the first. I would like to tell vim to use the second file entry. (So in this case, the location list should jump to source.js line 94, not line 20)

```
/Users/asdf/source.js:20:22,34:1: property hidden
Property not found in
/Users/asdf/source.js:94:10,106:3: object literal

/Users/asdf/source.js:25:14,18: identifier strin
Could not resolve name
```

[Here's the error format currently defined for flow](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/javascript/flow.vim): It works except that it uses the first filename instead of the second.

```
let errorformat =
    \ '%f:%l:%c:%n: %m,' .
    \ '%f:%l:%c: %m'
```

### Attempted Solution

I've been trying to use multi-line error formats, but I don't know what I'm doing. After reading `:help errorformat`, it seems like something like this should work, but it just loads the whole error into the message, with no file / line information. It also matches the second error using the first entry rather than the third.

```
let errorformat =
    \ '%E%m,%C%m,%Z%f:%l:%c:%n: %m,' .
    \ '%f:%l:%c:%n: %m,' .
    \ '%f:%l:%c: %m'
```

### Update

Thanks to lcd047, who pointed out that I'm not matching the correct output. Syntastic formats the error as follows, all on one line:

```
/Users/seanhess/projects/serials/web/app/model/source.js:20:22: property hidden Property not found in object literal (/Users/seanhess/projects/serials/web/app/model/source.js:94:10,106:3)
```

So, new question, how can I match the second location instead of the first? I think I'd prefer to ignore the first location.

Update Answer - this worked:

```
let errorformat =
    \ '%.%#: %m (%f:%l:%c\,%.%#),' .
    \ '%f:%l:%c:%n: %m,' .
    \ '%f:%l:%c: %m'
```

Comment: Your reading of the code in syntastic is wrong.  Syntastic uses the JSON output of flow, [re-formats it](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/cb9424c9ec241ee07e8c9b2231fe086f0d22ecc2/autoload/syntastic/preprocess.vim#L65-L126), and _then_ uses the `errorformat` you mention.  It does all that for a reason.  IMO your attempt to make it work without going through JSON stands little chances to succeed.

Comment: Wow thanks, you're right! It puts it all into one line: `/Users/seanhess/projects/serials/web/app/model/source.js:20:22: property hidden Property not found in o
bject literal (/Users/seanhess/projects/serials/web/app/model/source.js:94:10,106:3)`. That makes so much more sense, thanks!

Comment: Actually, the function `syntastic#preprocess#flow()` I mentioned above really decodes JSON, and then formats the results to conform to the `errorformat` in `flow.vim`, field by field.  It doesn't simply join the lines in the text output.  It doesn't read (nor care about) the text output of flow.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the file/line information because the %E specifies to use the rest of the line as the beginning of a multi-line message.

Try changing the "%Em" to "%E%f:%l:%c:%n: %m" for starters, since you basically want to keep all the original data being grabbed from the first version of errorformat.

You may want to change the "%Cm" to "%+Cm" to capture all of the lines in your error output.

The "%Z%f:%l:%c:%n: %m" looks good and should be used on the second line, since the %E will catch the first one.

Try that.

Comment: Sadly, `:%l:%c:%n: ` doesn't match `:20:22,34:1: `.

Comment: In that case, change the "%E..." to actually match the first line.  Careful with the comma!  There are some locales where "1000" is printed out as "1,000".

Comment: Wait, I"m confused. You're saying my multiline entry should have two lines: one with %E and a second with %Z, and they should both have all the file captures? I just tried it and the location list is using the file/line from the first line of the error. I want to ignore that one and use the file/line from the 3rd line of the error.

Comment: The %E __begins__ the multiline capture.  It will keep capturing until it matches the __end__ pattern, which is what the %Z is for.  This stuff is **not** easy.  For an example, you can look at the mips_c.vim compiler file by typing ":e $VIMRUNTIME/compiler/mips_c.vim".  I wrote that one and it took quite a bit of trial and error.  One other thing: note the order of the entries.

Comment: Thanks David, I don't know how to test this since my input isn't what I thought it was. Thank you for your help though!